# How can i put images side by side with html? I'm still begi

Tags: html, css-float

My friends creating an e-commerce web site and they want to show some options for customers, but they couldn't fix the image problem. They couldn't put images side by side. I want to help but my html knowledge is so basic. I try to use float method. So i will add my codes link, and i hope somebody help? Thanks.

[Codes are here](https://codeshare.io/5XdyXz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
<div class="highlights-banners highlight-banners-count-4">
```

To

```
<div class="highlights-banners highlight-banners-count-4" style="display: flex;">
```

To align items horizontally

try

**justify-content: space-evenly;**

**justify-content: space-around;**

**justify-content: center;**

Comment: It works, thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad that works for you. Please Mark this answer useful, so others can find it useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstap to make similar row divs and add three images in those divs. You can also use the code below:

```
<style>
    .img_div {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<div class="main_div">
    <div class="img_div"><img src="/images/1.png" height="300" width="230" /></div>
    <div class="img_div"><img src="/images/2.png" height="300" width="230" /></div>
    <div class="img_div"><img src="/images/3.png" height="300" width="230" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.highlights-banners-block {

```
display: inline-block;
```

}